# python csv module read csv split by comma but ignore the comma inside double or single quotes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file with column values contain some commas. Below are the examples:

```
Header: ID     Value           Content                                            Date
        1      34             "market, business"                               12/20/2013
        2      15             "market, business", yesterday, metric            11/21/2014
        3      18             "market," business and yesterday                 10/20/2014
        4      19              yesterday, today,                               11/22/2014
```

This is the format of the .csv file which if I open in Sublime Text, it appears in format:

```
1, 34, "market, business", 12/20/2013
2, 15, "market, business", "yesterday, metric, 11/21/2014
3, 18, "market," business and yesterday, 10/20/2014
4, 19, yesterday, today, 11/22/2014
```

But what I want is after the python csv reader program is:

```
[1, 34, "market, business", 12/20/2013]
[2, 15, "market, business" "yesterday metric, 11/21/2014]
[3, 18, "market," business and yesterday, 10/20/2014]
[4, 19, yesterday today, 11/22/2014]
```

These are just sample data I have, the "content" column is the headache here cause csv module uses "," as separator, I used

```
reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
```

It works for the first row if all the strings are inside one double quotes. But it doesn't apply for the third and second row if there're commas outside the quotes (single or double)

How can I solve the problem? I'm just using the traditional csv module in python now, does "panda" has the ability to solve the problem?

Thanks.

I made some updates, I think what I want is, method to specify comma at different places...
Now I paste here it seems unreasonable cause there's no way I can find inside csv module to tell the differences from separator "," and "," inside a field. Even excel can't...

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the list of "Related Questions" to the right. Do any of these answer your question?

Comment: Please post a sample of your csv and the desired DataFrame.

Comment: The desired Python lists would raise SyntaxErrors because there are unmatched quotation marks and strings without any quotation marks. Please fix.

Comment: If all your records have only 4 fields (fixed) there is a trivial way

Comment: @BhargavRao Unfortunately not.

Comment: Looks like your data is tab delimited from your raw data. Have you tried splitting based on a tab `\t` delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume

- each line begins with two ints separated by commas,
- each line ends with a date, separated by a comma
- everything remaining (in the middle) belongs in the third column

then your data could be parsed this way:

```
data = list()
with open('data') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split(',', 2)
        parts[2:4] = parts[2].rsplit(',', 1)
        parts[:2] = map(int, parts[:2])
        parts[2:] = map(str.strip, parts[2:])
        data.append(parts)

for row in data:
    print(row)
```

yields

```
[1, 34, '"market, business"', '12/20/2013']
[2, 15, '"market, business", "yesterday, metric', '11/21/2014']
[3, 18, '"market," business and yesterday', '10/20/2014']
[4, 19, 'yesterday, today', '11/22/2014']
```

---

You could then make a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Id','Value','Content','Date'])
print(df)
```

yields

```
   Id  Value                                 Content        Date
0   1     34                      "market, business"  12/20/2013
1   2     15  "market, business", "yesterday, metric  11/21/2014
2   3     18        "market," business and yesterday  10/20/2014
3   4     19                        yesterday, today  11/22/2014
```